Convolutional neural network for step/kink identification in 1D data
I am trying to implement a convolutional NN that shall be able to detect steps/kinks in 1D data.
A step is defined as a signal that changes in time and then becomes constant and vice versa. An example would be a machine displacement in a mechanical test that changes and then is held constant.
In order to train the model, I generated some synthetic data using the following simple function:
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import random
import math

def createStepFunction(steps: int, dy: float = 1.0, tHold: float = 3600.0, dt: float = 100.0):
    t = [0.0]
    y = [0.0]
    for _ in range(0, steps):
        holdTime = round(tHold*random.random(),0)
        t1 = t[-1] + round(dt*random.random(),0)
        t2 = t1 + holdTime
        t3 = t2 + round(dt*random.random(),0)
        t4 = t3 + holdTime

        y1 = y[-1] + dy*random.random()
        y2 = y1
        y3 = y2 - dy*random.random()
        y4 = y3
        t.extend([t1,t2,t3,t4])
        y.extend([y1,y2,y3,y4])

    tInterp = np.arange(0.0,t[-1]+0.5,1.0)
    yInterp = np.interp(tInterp, t, y)
    flag = np.array([1 if (elem in t and elem != 0.0) else 0 for elem in tInterp])
    # flagBool = [True if elem == 1 else False for elem in flag]
    return tInterp, yInterp, flag

t, y, flag = createStepFunction(200)
t = t/np.max(t)
gaussian_noise = np.random.normal(np.mean(y), 5e-4, len(t))
yn = y*gaussian_noise
yn = (yn - np.min(yn))/(np.max(yn) - np.min(yn))

I also added some Gaussian noise to the data. The result looks like this:
Example data
My features are one-hot vectors that are 0 everywhere except of the location of the step/kink, where they get assigned a value of 1.
I create batches of data using this function:
def createBatches(windowSize: int, arr):
    pos = 0
    batches = []

    while pos + windowSize < len(arr):
        values = arr[pos:pos+windowSize]
        batches.append(values)
        pos += windowSize
    
    return np.asarray(batches)

windowSize = 200
xBatch = createBatches(windowSize, yn)
yBatch = createBatches(windowSize, flag)
n_timesteps = xBatch.shape[1]
n_features = 1
n_outputs = yBatch.shape[1]

My Keras model looks like this:
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


# fit network
epochs = 1000
batch_size = 200
verbose = 1

history = model.fit(xBatch, yBatch, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

The architecture is similar to an example I found in a book.
However, the model does not seem to fit to the provided data. The loss does not decrease significantly and the accuracy is very poor. I tried various parameters without success.
What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the data I generate for training?
Is it even possible to use this approach for my purpose?

I guess your features are not really a one-hot vector meaning you only have one value of 1 but rather you have a 1 at every instance of a step/kink?

You are right, my bad! There is a 1 at every instance of a kink/step in my feature data.
